# Why is knitting a pdf_document in Rstudio extraordinarily slow now?

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

Knitting the following `Rmd` file now takes ~2 minutes on a 2020 MacBook Pro:

```
---
title: "Statistical report "
author: "author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---
``{r}
devtools::session_info()
``
```

*I know that the chunk above has only two tick marks, but I couldn't figure out how to format the code correctly here.*

Taking 2 minutes essentially makes knitting to a PDF an unusable feature.

Here is the output of `devtools::session_info()`:

```
## - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
##  setting  value                       
##  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
##  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.6      
##  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
##  ui       X11                         
##  language (EN)                        
##  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
##  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
##  tz       America/New_York            
##  date     2020-10-28                  
## 
## - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
##  package     * version date       lib source        
##  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  backports     1.1.10  2020-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  callr         3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  cli           2.1.0   2020-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  devtools      2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
##  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  knitr         1.30    2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  ps            1.4.0   2020-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  rlang         0.4.8   2020-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  rmarkdown     2.5     2020-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  usethis       1.6.3   2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  xfun          0.18    2020-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
## 
## [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```

And here's the Rmarkdown log:

```
processing file: statistical_report.Rmd
  |....................................................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments


output file: statistical_report.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS statistical_report.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output statistical_report.tex --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tint/rmarkdown/templates/tintPdf/resources/tintPdf-template.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --natbib --variable 'documentclass:tufte-handout'
```

Does anyone have a suggestion about what is making this take so long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`  and then rerunning your report

Comment: Should it still take 2 minutes, even if the only content being rendered is the title/author from the YAML header? In other words, does this behavior make sense if I am loading no packages?